# I want to add all the images stored in a folder to a website in django

Tags: python, django

How can I loop through images in a folder and add them to the website?

I want to make a website in which users can upload their photos and every other user can access it.

I want to create a website in which all the users can upload their images and every other user can access that image. All the uploaded images are stored in a media folder. What I want is to add all those images to the html file so that other users can access those images.
Please help me on displaying the images on the browser (html file)

Suppose I have a photo folder called image_post which stores the photos that users upload.
So, I just want to display all those images in a html file, and for that I think I should use a for loop:

```
{% extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
{% load static %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1>this is the explore page</h1>
  <h4>Go to the home page to post more images</h4>
  {% for images in post_images %}
    <div class=" col-md-4 ">
      {{ images.title }}
      <img src="{{ images.image.url }}" alt="There was an error">
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h3>Please login first to have a look at all the images which are 
posted by other users.</h3>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure if the above method is correct because we cannot use a for loop in html file to loop through the images of a folder.
Is there any method by which I can add the images to the html, like the google photos site where all the images are displayed?

Comment: Can you share some of the code and write more detailed question?

Comment: I haven't coded yet, because I wanted to know how to solve the above issue.

Comment: That method is correct step in that direction. It seems that you're asking for more of a general Django architecture questions. Maybe you can reword your question to make it clearer what would support you in what you'd like to do.

Comment: Is this question clearer than before?

Comment: It feels too general. You probably should just start coding and then ask specific question once you get stuck. Your general approach looks correct.